# Project list not being displayed by Angular, no error in chrome dev console

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

So i'm trying to build a bug tracker with angular and spring boot. I managed to render a list of employees from the database and it works fine. I encountered the cross origin error but i have fixed it by adding @CrossOrigin in spring repositories.

Now im trying to do the same thing with a list of projects, by doing the same process of the employees list, but i cant display it. There are no errors in the chrome debug console.

Augury extension show the state of the components and the employee list have indeed the populated array.
But for the project component there is no array at all.

This is my project-list-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from 'src/app/common/project';
import { ProjectService } from 'src/app/services/project.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-list',
  //templateUrl: './project-list-table.component.html',
  templateUrl: './project-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-list.component.css']
})
export class ProjectListComponent implements OnInit {

  projects: Project[];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listProjects();
  }

  listProjects(){
    this.projectService.getProjectList().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.projects = data;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

This is my project.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Project } from '../common/project';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/projects';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getProjectList(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response._embedded.projects)
    );
  }
}

interface GetResponse {
 _embedded: {
   projects: Project[];
 }
}
```

And this is my project-list.component.html:

```
<p *ngFor="let tempProject of projects">
  {{ tempProject.projectName }}, {{ tempProject.description }}, {{ tempProject.stage }}
</p>
```

I have added the Project Service to the app module providers.
I have added the app-project-list selector to the app.component.html

I have the single project class defined in the same folder as the employee.
The fields matches the json that i receive from spring rest api.
The endpoint is exposes so if i navigate to the baseUrl of Projects they are shown.

What im wondering if there are some problems with the subscribing in the service.ts? They should be two separate observable right?
Or has it something to do with being asyncronous operations?
Or the fact that i'm injecting the same httpClient?
Sorry i'm new to this stuff.

Map log:

```
{_embedded: {…}, _links: {…}, page: {…}}
page:
number: 0
size: 20
totalElements: 3
totalPages: 1
__proto__: Object
_embedded:
project: Array(3)
0: {projectName: "Game App", description: "A simple game", stage: "Completed", _links: {…}}
1: {projectName: "Web Browser", description: "A complicated browser", stage: "In progress", _links: {…}}
2: {projectName: "Music Player", description: "A intermediate musica player", stage: "Not started", _links: {…}}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
_links:
profile: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/projects"}
self: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/projects"}
__proto__: Object
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ ()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: could you add a breakpoint or console.log(data) above this.projects = data; in your listProjects method to determine if you really got the data ?

Comment: your code seems fine, you have to place a breakpoint inside map in service and check what you are receiving in response.

Comment: So i have tried and i got undefined for projects and doing the same thing for employeelist() i indeed get the 5 elements for the employees array

Comment: @Ghevi: Do a console log inside the service map and see the actual structure of the data from the backend.

Comment: @Michael D sorry i tried to figure it out but i dont know how to do the console log after map(response=>response._embedded.projects));

Comment: @Ghevi try: `map(response => { console.log(response); return response._embedded.projects; }))`

Comment: @Michael D i will add the log in the question i tried to expand some lines, tell if u need to see more
This are not expanded:
{_embedded: {…}, _links: {…}, page: {…}}
page: {size: 20, totalElements: 3, totalPages: 1, number: 0}
_embedded: {project: Array(3)}
_links: {self: {…}, profile: {…}}
__proto__: Object

Comment: It appears the property is called `project` not `projects`. I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the object you've posted, it appears the property is called `project` not `projects`. So try the following

```js
getProjectList(): Observable<Project[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
    map(response => response._embedded.project)      // <-- replace `projects` with `project`
  );
}
```

Comment: oh good lord, thank you a lot this was the issue. How could i not have seen it.
I had a typo in the spring Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "project", path = "projects") instead of collectionResourceRel = "projects"

Comment: @Ghevi: This isn't first time I am stumbling across such a tiny typo. It happens quite often and are a huge resource drain.

Comment: do u have any suggestion or advice to avoid them?

Comment: Unfortunately neither linters nor IDEs can help us in such issues. I can only say try to look in obvious places. I've also had a scenario where the key was `project:`. So the object went like `'project:': [...]`, and it was time consuming as well.